# How to catch user pressing escape key in Atom Package

Tags: atom-editor

I am developing an Atom package, and I have certain commands that get executed when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd>.

The first time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd>, Atom enters a "mode" where things happen differently.  Now, I think I know how to do that part. But I don't know how to tell atom to hijack the Escape key.

Comment: Sounds interesting, if you are looking for further inspiration you could have a look at [vim-mode](https://atom.io/packages/vim-mode) which has a very similar function in that you enter `Insert` mode where you can enter characters and you press `Esc` to exit insert mode.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign a command to <kbd>Esc</kbd> through your package keymap.

Example:

```
'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'escape': 'my-package:do-stuff'
```

If your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> shortcut creates a custom view, you would want to limit your shortcut to its CSS selector.

Example:

```
'.my-custom-view':
  'escape': 'my-package:do-stuff'
```

Further reading:

- [Atom Flight Manual: Keymaps In-Depth](http://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/)
- [Atom API: KeymapManager](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.7.1/KeymapManager#instance-keystrokeForKeyboardEvent)